# How to add comment to the old answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

I am sorry for this question. Just do not know where to ask. I have found an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4414040/1746522 for my issue. The code in this answer has a small bug. It took me some hours to figure it out and I wanted to add a comment to this answer with the small correction as suggestion. However I do not see any comment form or link "add comment". Only a possibility to add new answer.

Is it because the answer is old or due to my reputation or ...? Thank you.

Comment: It's reputation (you need 50), see http://stackoverflow.com/privileges